# C preprocessor replace multiple arguments

Tags: c-preprocessor

I want `FUNC(x1, x2, x3, etc..)` to be replaced with

```
FUNC2(x1);
FUNC2(x2);
FUNC2(x3);
etc..
```

I tried but failed with varargs. Both `FUNC` and `FUNC2` must be macros.

Comment: So the question is: How do I apply a macro named FUNC2 to each argument in a `__VA_ARGS__` list?

Comment: @PSkocik Edited the question to make it more clear. I have a macro `FUNC2` which takes 1 argument and the question is how to make a macro `FUNC` that applie the macro `FUNC2` to each of its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It's doable but non-trivial.

I'm using a `BX_foreach(Joiner,Function,...)` macro for this implemented as follows
(generated for about 8 arguments -- you should be able to figure out how to generated it for more):

```
#define BX_foreach(Join,What, ...) BX_foreach_(BX_argc(__VA_ARGS__), Join, What, __VA_ARGS__)

#define BX_foreach_(N, Join, What, ...) BX_paste(BX_cat(BX_foreach_, N)(Join, What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define BX_cat(X,Y)  BX_cat_(X,Y) //{{{
#define BX_cat_(X,Y) X##Y //}}}
#define BX_call_first(Fn,...) Fn ( __VA_ARGS__ )
#define BX_paste(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define BX_argc(...) BX_argc_(X,__VA_ARGS__) //{{{
#define BX_argc_(...) BX_argc__(,__VA_ARGS__,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,0)
#define BX_argc__(_,_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,Cnt,...) Cnt //}}}
#define BX_foreach_1(Join, What,  x) BX_call_first(What,  x)
#define BX_foreach_2(Join, What,  x,...)BX_call_first(What,x) Join BX_foreach_1(Join, What,  __VA_ARGS__)
#define BX_foreach_3(Join, What,  x,...)BX_call_first(What,x) Join BX_foreach_2(Join, What,  __VA_ARGS__)
#define BX_foreach_4(Join, What,  x,...)BX_call_first(What,x) Join BX_foreach_3(Join, What,  __VA_ARGS__)
#define BX_foreach_5(Join, What,  x,...)BX_call_first(What,x) Join BX_foreach_4(Join, What,  __VA_ARGS__)
#define BX_foreach_6(Join, What,  x,...)BX_call_first(What,x) Join BX_foreach_5(Join, What,  __VA_ARGS__)
#define BX_foreach_7(Join, What,  x,...)BX_call_first(What,x) Join BX_foreach_6(Join, What,  __VA_ARGS__)
```

With it, you can do:

```
#define FUNC(X) foo(X)
BX_foreach(;,FUNC,x1,x2,x3)
```

and [have it expand to](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/RO0nxx)

```
foo(x1) ; foo(x2) ; foo(x3)
```

Comment: The example you provided does not work when I try it. BX_foreach is not defined. Did you mean to write BX_foreach_(;,FUNC,x1,x2,x3) ? I wrote a minimal example for testing purposes, but it does not compile. Could you maybe tell me whats wrong with how I use it? https://godbolt.org/z/Y95Qem

Comment: CompilerExplorer link https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/RO0nxx (also in the new edit of the answer).